# Instruction Cycle max and min?

Tags: cpu-architecture, machine-instruction

[image: 1]

I understood the desciribe of the following instruction cycle part. But what is the mean of minumum and maximum instruction cycle? What kind of answer expecting from me? Didn't get it and never heard about min max instruction cycle in class.

Leaved a image for you
Thanks

Comment: I think they're asking about the min and max time for any given instruction.  Perhaps in number of states, which would make sense if each state in the diagram took one cycle.  Otherwise you'd need more info, like total picoseconds if each stage has a different time, or in clock cycles if you have times in cycles for each stage.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "cycle" they're talking about is in the directed graph, to traverse the nodes and get back to the "instruction complete" state.  Assuming correct English grammar, their phrasing isn't really compatible with clock cycles as a meaning.  Oh, so actually maybe they just want you to find the longest and shortest path through the directed graph.  But without knowing how many operands an instruction can have, we can't say.

Comment: Start by answering the question: what's the shortest path from Instruction Fetch to Instruction Fetch?  Then consider the duration of each node in the shortest path as Peter says (is it 1 cycle each?).  Do the same for longest.   Hint: there's not enough information in the graph image alone to be sure if there is a min or max on operand fetch or store counts; you might have to look to other materials for that information (one such reference \ material might be the instruction encodings as those often impose limits on operands).  String & Vector instructions may differ from other instructions.